# PHP+MongoDB: finding more than one query

Tags: php, mongodb, asynchronous

In general, my script is really simple:

1. findOne by queryX in collectionA
2. findOne by queryX in collectionB (independent from [1])
3. Go on with the results from both, 1 and 2.

Now I have the delay: (2) does not start before (1) is finally completed.

Does the mongodb PHP driver provide an option to pass found queries asynchronously?

Let's say one query takes 5 seconds and two queries takes another 5 seconds.
This will increase the script's runtime from 10 to 5 in my scenario.

Comment: The PHP driver is not async

Comment: Other than opening new threads for each call which I prolly would not recommend I would say no for the min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB PHP driver is not capable of doing this today, and infact the MongoDB database itself does not return results out of order either, so this would be really difficult to implement for the driver with out specific support for it at the database level.

I do believe such functionality is in the works, but it is a major shift, so I don't expect it in the upcoming development series (2.5.x) which will lead to the next production release (2.6.x).